# Dataflow in OpenShift: Configure memory for individual Dataflow tasks

Tags: openshift, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'd like to configure individual dataflow tasks with their own memory request and limit values. The default configuration works fine for most tasks, but we have some tasks with higher memory needs. We can start those tasks from dataflow with their own properties, overriding the default configuration. But is it possible to have a configuration in the dataflow-config on OpenShift for individual tasks? (So that we don't have to use those overriding arguments each time we start the task).

Something like this:

```
deployer:
      kubernetes:
        requests:
          memory: '256Mi'
          cpu: '1m'
        limits:
          memory: '4Gi'
          cpu: '6000m'
my-individual-task:
          kubernetes:
            requests:
              memory: '8G'
            limits:
              memory :'8G'
```

Testing it with this configuration, the "my-individual-task" had the default configuration with 256Mi-4Gi instead of 8G-8G. (I restarted the dataflow pod with the new configuration before starting the task).⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set the task specific properties as **server** level properties. Instead, you can set these properties as task launch properties when launching the task. For instance:

```
task launch mytask --properties "deployer.my-individual-task.kubernetes.requests.memory=8G,deployer.my-individual-task.kubernetes.limits.memory=8G"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Testing it with this configuration, the "my-individual-task" had the default configuration with 256Mi-4Gi instead of 8G-8G

In my experience, the only way to successfully change the memory and CPU for an individual task is to provide the following properties when launching the task from the Data Flow Server UI (as properties) or when using the Task Java DSL :

```
deployer.<application>.kubernetes.limits.cpu=1000m
deployer.<application>.kubernetes.limits.memory=1024Mi
deployer.<application>.kubernetes.requests.cpu=800m
deployer.<application>.kubernetes.requests.memory=640Mi
```

Note : Specifying these in the application.properties or applicaiton.yaml file does not have any effect whatsoever.